# One or more paramater were not specified for the subreport - Visual Studio 2017 /SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating an SSRS report with 9 Subreports on it using Visual Studio 2017 and when I tested it, it was working perfectly but then I realized that the blank width area was too big so I decided to reduce the size

[image: the highlighted area is what I wanted to reduce]

This is the final result after reduced the blank width area

[image]

Since I just changed the width size, I did not imagine that this will cause any issue on the report but when I executed the "preview" again, I've got the error below:

[image]

The subreports don't require any parameters to work and the report was working just fine before the width change. And I 100% believe this is an issue with Visual Studio because if I delete the .rdl file, re-create it and add the subreports again it will work but for any basic change on the report, it will start failing again. Do you know a solution to fix this?